# Написание ОС. Странная ошибка

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, osdev

Пишу свою ОС. Вроде всё идёт хорошо (наверное даже слишком). Проблема в том, что управление на вторую часть загрузчика передаётся сразу после считывания секторов диска. Как такое возможно?

- `boot1.asm`:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]
    jmp boot

BOOT2_OFFSET    equ 0x1000

boot:
    mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

    mov bx, MSG_BOOT1
    call print
    call print_nl

    call load_boot2

    jmp $

load_boot2:
    mov bx, MSG_BOOT2_LOAD
    call print
    call print_nl

    mov bx, BOOT2_OFFSET
    mov dh, 16
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    call disk_load

    jmp $

%include "disk.asm"
%include "print.asm"

BOOT_DRIVE      db 0
MSG_BOOT1       db "Loading in BOOT1...", 0
MSG_BOOT2_LOAD  db "Loading BOOT2.bin...", 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

- `disk.asm`:

```
; load 'dh' sectors from drive 'dl' into ES:BX
disk_load:
    pusha
    push dx

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, dh
    mov cl, 0x02
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov dh, 0x00

    int 0x13
    jc disk_error
    jnc disk_success

    pop dx
    cmp al, dh
    jne sectors_error
    popa
    ret

disk_success:
    mov bx, DISK_SUCCESS
    call print
    call print_nl
    ret

disk_error:
    mov bx, DISK_ERR
    call print
    call print_nl
    jmp $

sectors_error:
    mov bx, SECT_ERR
    call print
    jmp $

DISK_ERR:       db "Disk read error!", 0
SECT_ERR:       db "Incorrect number of sectors read!", 0
DISK_SUCCESS:   db "Disk read success!", 0
```

- `print.asm`:

```
print:
    pusha

start:
    mov al, [bx]
    cmp al, 0 
    je done
    add bx, 1
    jmp start

done:
    popa
    ret

print_nl:
    pusha
    
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x0a
    int 0x10
    mov al, 0x0d
    int 0x10
    
    popa
    ret
```

- `boot2.asm`

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x1000]
    jmp boot2

boot2:
    mov bx, MSG_BOOT2
    call print
    call print_nl

    jmp $

%include "print.asm"

MSG_BOOT2       db "Loading in BOOT2...", 0
```

- Вывод `qemu`:

[image: File1]

- Собираю так:

  1. `nasm boot1.asm -f bin -o boot1.bin`
  2. `nasm boot2.asm -f bin -o boot2.bin`
  3. `cat boot1.bin boot2.bin > os.bin`
  4. `qemu-system-i386 -fda os.bin`

Comment: По вашим правкам: не нужно названия программ типа Visual Studio Code, monodevelop, языков программирования, и т.д. оборачивать в обратные апострофы, это не код все-таки (в остальном правки более-менее нормальные)

Comment: @insolor, согласен, это не код, но становится более заметным какую IDE или язык программирования использует человек. Разве не так?

Comment: IDE (если требуется) и язык указываются в метках вопроса. Дополнительно выделять их в тексте не нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `disk_load` в стек сохраняются регистры и `dx` (и собственно зачем `dx` отдельно сохранять?):

```
disk_load:
    pusha
    push dx
```

но в ветке `disk_success` они оттуда не достаются:

```
disk_success:
    mov bx, DISK_SUCCESS
    call print
    call print_nl
    ret
```

Вот при `ret`'е и происходит переход по адресу, который был до этого в `dx`, а это `0x1000` (`dh`=`16` `dl`=`0`), что очень «удобно» т.к. это совпадает с тем адресом, куда загружается вторая часть загрузчика...

Comment: Так и есть, но почему если  перед `ret` поменять значение в регистре `dh` (`mov dh, 2`)  а в `dl` оставить прежнее, то происходит переход по тому же адресу?

Comment: @SurfaceStack, потому что адрес возврата достаётся из стека, значение в регистре в момент `ret` не имеет значения...